# JMeter Random Variable Element not recognise variable from previous step

Tags: variables, jmeter

tl;dr
When I use my variable created in **Regular Expression Extractor** I cannot use it in **Random Variable** as *Maximum Value*

Long description:

- My test structure:

  - [image]
- I have variable `my_test` what is crated in **Regular Expression Extractor**

  - request: GET `//echo.getpostman.com/get?test=123`
  - regex:
  - [image]
- Then I want it use as *Maximum Value* in  **Regular Expression Extractor**

  - [image]
- So finally I can make request:

  - `//echo.getpostman.com/get?test=${rand}`

Unfortunately I get error from **Random Variable**
`2016/10/07 07:52:41 ERROR - jmeter.config.RandomVariableConfig: maximum(${my_test}) must be > minimum1)`

Why `my_test` is not evaluated?

I have tried `${__javaScript(parseInt('${my_test}'))}` but it looks like it is evaluated before my variable initialization 
`2016/10/07 08:06:01 ERROR - jmeter.config.RandomVariableConfig: maximum(NaN) must be > minimum1)`
If I initialize this variable in **Test Plan** in *User Defined Variables* value from that setting will be used - not updated by regex.

I know that I can do `//echo.getpostman.com/get?test=${__Random(0,${my_test})}`
I'm just curious how pass my variable as value for *Maximum Value* in  **Regular Expression Extractor**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random Variable is a **Config Element** and it will be executed first before any other components get executed first.

> 4.9 Execution order
>
> 1. Configuration elements
> 2. Pre-Processors
> 3. Timers
> 4. Sampler
> 5. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
> 6. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
> 7. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

If two or more Config elements present in the Test Plan, then they will be executed in the order they appear in the Test Plan.

Check the execution order and Scope here:
Refer 4.9 7 4.10 here [Execution Order and Scope Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html)

So, first Random Variable is evaluated first and then Sampler and then regular expression extractor.

When you used User Defined Variables, which is another Config Element, and probably you put it before Random Variable, so it evaluated the expression as you already defined the value for "my_test". But it won't override the value you captured in Regular Expression Extractor.

To solve your problem (one probable solution):

you can use different thread groups. In first thread group, you capture the value and in second thread group, you use the value.

1. Run Thread Groups consecutively.
2. Use BeanShell Assertion to capture the value by setProperty. (in first thread group)
3. Use value using __property() (in thread group)

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [Random Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) element does not evaluate variables, maybe it worth creating an issue in [JMeter Issue Tracker](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

As a workaround you can substitute it with [__Random()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function directly where required like:

- `${__Random(1,${my_test},)}` - if you need the value right away, directly in you URL:

  ```
  //echo.getpostman.com/get?test=${__Random(1,${my_test},)}
  ```
- `${__Random(1,${my_test},rand)}` - if if you need to store the value into `${rand}` variable as well

See:

- [Using JMeter Functions](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) article for extended information on this and others JMeter Functions.
- [Function Helper Dialog](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) - an utility helping to generate correct function syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's valid for me to comment on a problem I had, I set the random variable and it didn't work at all, I did everything I could to try to solve it.
In the end my problem was a space at the beginning of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is you can use a Beanshell Postprocessor to write the RegEx value to the variable name.
After that you can use it as ${variable_name}

NB: Beanshell function vars.get can be used for getting regex value and vars.put can be used for putting it into your variable.